# railsのcontrollerの中でcurrent_page?を使いたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

controllerの中で`current_page?(hoge_path)`を使うと以下の様なエラーになってしまいます。

```
undefined method `current_page?'
```

controllerの中ではどのようにpathを判定すればいいのでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

ある`controller`の`action`がどのようなURLになるのか調べるには`url_for`を利用します。
`xxxx_path`と比較するなら以下のようになるかと思います。

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    p users_path == url_for(controller: controller_name, action: action_name, only_path: true)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Controllerの中では `ApplicationController.helpers.xxxxxxxx` のように呼び出せば helper を利用することが出来ますが、`current_page?` は動作しません。

やりたいことは現在のコントローラ・アクションをチェックすることだと思いますので、

- controller_name
- action_name

で判定してはいかがでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

こういうアプローチのお行儀がいいかどうかは別として、`ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper`をincludeすれば`current_page?`は使えますね。

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  def index
    Rails.logger.debug current_page?(users_path) # => true
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```